# Checkpoint VPN client not connecting, Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, networking, debian, vpn

Edit: what I'm looking for here is help finding out what's going on at the OS level, so that I can find out for sure whether the problem is on my end or my workplace's end, or in between. I'm not really after help *fixing* the problem! Thanks :)

My employer provides a VPN service using a Checkpoint VPN product (uncertain exactly which); there are two routes into the network from a Linux machine, either using Checkpoint's SNX command line client, or using a web portal that runs a Java applet.

In the past, I was able to connect without any problem using the client, but it's recently ceased to work, giving me the following:

```
Check Point's Linux SNX
build 800007027
Please enter your password:
SNX: Cannot establish connection to SSL Network Extender gateway. Try to reconnect.
```

The result is that I now have to use the Java applet. The admins are sure that nothing's changed on their end, and I'm 95% sure that nothing's changed on mine. I'd much rather use the SNX client than have to have Java in my browser.

How can I go about tracking down where the fault lies? I am not well-versed in much more than the basics as far as networking goes.

Answer (score 0):

In general, googling your error message helps: have you seen this Web page, *https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk30772*?

Don't be fooled by the disclaimer that it concerns a discontinued product, the page was last updated on march 13th, 2014. Basically, it is a matter of traffic on port 443 being blocked.

As per your system admins claim that nothing changed on their side, did they really change nothing in OpenSSL? I find it hard to believe.

Comment: Yes, I've seen it, and it doesn't help - firstly, 443 isn't blocked on my end, and secondly, the web portal Java applet (which is what the support article is talking about) works fine for me.
[edit: pressed enter too soon!] And yes, I'm not totally convinced by the claim nothing's changed on the host end either - what I'm asking is how I can go about pinning down where the fault lies.

Comment: good thinking re: OpenSSL, though, but this started several months ago, so long before Heartbleed!

Comment: @SnewsleyPies Try one of those services which will try to contact an IP address on a port you specify, and report whether the port is reachable or not, like http://www.canyouseeme.org/

Comment: How will that help? I'm not hosting any services; I'm trying to connect to one, and I know I can connect to it through the other client.

Comment: @SnewsleyPies If you assume that the CLI and Java applet work exactly the same way, then obviously there is no solution to your problem. As port 443 being unreachable  as the source of the precise error message you receive, it is Check Point page that says as much, not me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I'm explaining things terribly well here - thanks for trying, though!

I *believe* that the Java applet is just a wrapper that runs the console client; since one works and the other doesn't, I want to find out what's going on under the bonnet. What I'm hoping for is some guidance on how to find out what is and isn't happening at the OS level, rather than more experimentation with the apps themselves - I'll update my question to make this clearer.

Comment: Try using telnet to connect to the endpoint url, on port 443.